# Will Job backoff limit ever be reached with `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"` and healthy nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

As per k8s docs:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-backoff-failure-policy

> Note: If your job has restartPolicy = "OnFailure", keep in mind that your Pod running the Job will be terminated once the job backoff limit has been reached. This can make debugging the Job's executable more difficult. We suggest setting restartPolicy = "Never" when debugging the Job or using a logging system to ensure output from failed Jobs is not lost inadvertently.

I am very confused with this note:

1. If I understand correctly backoff count increments with failed Pod only, not failed container. So with `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"` same container in Pod will restart in infinity loop, never increasing backoff count unless node fails?
2. If #1 is correct - then this footnote makes no sense as there is no difference either with `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"` or `restartPolicy = "Never"` - last Pod will be lost with the node failure anyway.
3. Footnote could make some sense in case of parallel execution - e.g. if there are 2 Pods with `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"` and backoff limit set to 2. So if the first pod is in error loop, and second pod failed 2 times due to node issues, first pod is terminated by Job controller to exit error loop. Is that what this footnote about? Seems like an extreme long shot to me.

I feel like there is some easier logical reason in Pod lifecycle that leads to this behaviour, but still cant put my finger on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. If I understand correctly backoff count increments with failed Pod only, not failed container.

Yes, the backoff count increments only with a failed Pod, not with a failed container. If the container fails but the Pod is healthy (e.g., node issues), then with `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"`, the container within the Pod will be restarted indefinitely without increasing the backoff count. The Job's backoff limit will not be reached as long as the Pod itself does not fail.

> 2. If #1 is correct - then this footnote makes no sense as there is no difference either with `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"` or `restartPolicy = "Never"`

The primary difference is that with `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"`, the container will keep restarting within the same Pod if it fails, whereas with `restartPolicy = "Never"`, it will not restart. If a Pod fails, both policies will result in the Job controller tracking the failure towards the backoff limit.

You are right that node failure will cause the last Pod to be lost in both cases.

> 3. Footnote could make some sense in case of parallel execution

The footnote seems more focused on the difficulty of debugging when using `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"`, as the continual restarting of the container could lead to loss of logs or make it more challenging to examine the state of a failed container.

This is more about best practices for debugging rather than describing a specific edge case in Pod lifecycle. For debugging purposes, using `restartPolicy = "Never"` would allow easier inspection of failed containers without them being restarted, which could be helpful for troubleshooting.

---

If all this was not confusing enough, you also have [Backoff limit per index](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#backoff-limit-per-index) (alpha, K8s 1.28+), which specifically affects Indexed Jobs, where each `Pod` corresponds to an index, and allows a more fine-grained control over the failure handling for each index.

---

> I fell like there is some easier logical reason in Pod lifecycle that leads to this behaviour, but still cant put my finger on it.

The confusion might stem from the apparent contradiction that setting `restartPolicy = "OnFailure"` could cause a Job to terminate when the backoff limit is reached, even though this policy restarts containers indefinitely if the Pod itself does not fail.

So, the "easier logical reason" in Pod lifecycle leading to this behavior is how the `restartPolicy` interacts with the container and Pod states. It is about the scope and level at which the restarts are managed (container vs. Pod), and how these settings affect the ability to debug and control `Job` execution.